# Drawing laser patterns using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a simple way to draw these patterns using Tikz

[image]

Update: I'm trying to work on importing the data from Matlab to latex, but when I save the data by converting the m.file to latex it doesn't work. Is there any hint on how to export the data to latex so I can use it in tikz

Comment: All you need is a 2D FFT.  I would **not** use pgfmath for that, but rather store the numbers into a data file.  See the table feature of pgfplots, or pgfpplotstable.

Comment: you mean I should use Matlab to generate the data files and then import them to latex

Comment: Das ist eine grosse Zehn Vier guter Kamerad! (yes)